# i have a single character in my cursor.How to convert that to string and display that on alert box?

Tags: android

i have a single character in my cursor.How to convert that to string and display that on alert box?

here is my code...

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String a,c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("dat", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rk(num integer,alph char);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('1','a');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('2','b');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('3','c');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('4','d');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO rk VALUES('5','e');");
    }

    public void disp(View view){
      EditText ed;
      ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      a=ed.getText().toString();
      Cursor b=db.rawQuery("SELECT alph FROM rk WHERE num='a';",null);
      c=b.getString(b.getColumnIndex("alph"));
      Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      builder.setMessage(c);
      AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
      alert.show();

}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: could not execute method of the activity

Comment: I mean what exactly happens when you try to run this code?

Comment: i'm getting an illegal state exception at the line

Comment: c=b.getString(b.getColumnIndex("alph"));

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are using a as string instead of String object which holds the value of edit text. So update your query as follows,

```
a=ed.getText().toString();

Cursor b=db.rawQuery("SELECT alph FROM rk WHERE num='" + a +"'",null);

if (b.getCount() > 0 ) {
      c=b.getString(b.getColumnIndex("alph"));
      showMessage(c);
} else {
      showMessage("No record match");
}


private void showMessage(String msg) {
     Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      builder.setMessage(msg);
      AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
      alert.show();
}
```

Comment: a=ed.getText().toString();
      Cursor b=db.rawQuery("SELECT alph FROM rk WHERE num='a';",null);

Answer (score 0):

The cursor object already holds only the values from the column "alph" and you are trying to once again query the index here  `c=b.getString(b.getColumnIndex("alph"));`. This I think is causing the issue.

So, instead you can directly try to print the values of cursor, like this,

```
  c=b.getString(0);
```